# Fail to Maven Build due to an API incompatibility

Tags: java, eclipse, api, maven, servlets

I want to build a maven project using Servlet API.However,I failed and error comes that:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war (default-war) on project myfirstservlet: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null
```

I do know a little for the problem but still not know how to solve it.Should I download another version of JDK、JRE or something else,or just rewrite my code?
Here is my code of pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mavenservlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>myfirstservlet</artifactId>
  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myfirstservlet Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>myfirstservlet</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mavenservlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfirstservlet</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
            <webResources>
               <resource>
                  <directory>WebContent</directory>
               </resource>
            </webResources>
         </configuration>
                </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you put your own servlet as plugin into the POM?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do in the pom.xml but i failed.I guess it may the incompatibility of tomcat、jre、jdk and so on in different versions that causes such a problem.

Comment: I'have already done it by using another code which costs me some money.It confuses me.I'd love to share it for the followers.Still thanks for J Fabian Meier for his sincere help  @J Fabian Meier

Answer (score 0):

here is the right code and it costs me some money.I still can't konw how it works.But I'd love to share it for the followers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mavenservlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfirstservlet</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to change the default plugin version, your default maybe 2.2 or 3.0.0 so read carefully the error maven-war-plugin mentioned there.

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

]